# Почему не работает сокращенная запись transition?

Tags: css3, css-animation, transition

Доброго дня! 
Вопрос прост, почему не работает сокращенная запись transition? 
http://jsfiddle.net/Xj82v/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ прост, вместо easy писать ease: http://jsfiddle.net/rh4DY/

Comment: Большое спасибо)) Видимо пора отдохнуть)